# Mongodb, find entries from name or categories from a list of defined categories

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Using mongodb, I am trying to find the entries where the `name` matches the user input among a definite list of categories OR where the categories from the same list match the user input.

I want to filter the collection to only show these categories `["major olympian", "twelve titan", "primordial deity"]`

The user can search for a `name` from one of these categories or can search through the categories to display all the entries from the categories that matched the user input and are mentioned in the array

Before the collection was filtered this worked but now I only want the results from the filtered array of categories:

```
     let _query = {
  '$or': [
    {
      "name": {
        "$regex": search,
        "$options": "i"
      }
    },
    {
      "category": {
        "$regex": search,
        "$options": "i"
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

**Here is a concrete example:**

If the user type `an` it will return all entries where `name` contains `an` from categories `["major olympian", "twelve titan", "primordial deity"]` as well as all the entries from `major olympian` and `twelve titan`

Here is a sample of my collection with one category `creature` that is **never** displayed :

```
        {
            "name": "Zeus",
            "greekName": "Ζεύς, Zeus",
            "romanName": "Jupiter",
            "description": "King of the gods, ruler of Mount Olympus, and god of the sky, weather, thunder, lightning, law, order, and justice. He is the youngest son of Cronus and Rhea. He overthrew Cronus and gained the sovereignty of heaven for himself. In art he is depicted as a regal, mature man with a sturdy figure and dark beard. His usual attributes are the royal scepter and the lightning bolt. His sacred animals include the eagle and the bull. His Roman counterpart is Jupiter, also known as Jove.",
     "category": "major olympian"
          },
          {
            "name": "Ophiogenean dragon",
            "greekName": "",
            "romanName": "",
            "description": "a dragon that guarded Artemis' sacred grove in Mysia.",
            "category": "creature",
          },
          {
            "greekName": "Ἀχλύς (Akhlýs)",
            "name": "Achlys",
            "description": "The goddess of poisons and the \"Death-Mist\", and             personification of misery and sadness. Said to have existed before Chaos itself.",
            "category": "primordial deity",
            "romanName": ""
           }
```

Comment: You can `$and` the list of categories  with your existing `$or` query. Wouldn't that work ?

Comment: oh ! I think it does :) Thanks ! I think I am grasping how these queries work.

Comment: Here is the simplied version `const _query = {
 category: {
  $in: TEMP_CATEGORIES
 },
 '$or': [{
  "name": {
   "$regex": search,
   "$options": "i"
  }
 }, {
  "category": {
   "$regex": search,
   "$options": "i"
  }
 }]
};`

Comment: Thanks ! I'll try it. If you want to answer, i'll upvote it, cause I was about to give up for the night :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this.

```
const _query = {
    category: {
        $in: TEMP_CATEGORIES
    },
    '$or': [{
        "name": {
            "$regex": search,
            "$options": "i"
        }
    }, {
        "category": {
            "$regex": search,
            "$options": "i"
        }
    }]
};
```

Comment: Looks a lot cleaner too !

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Veeram comment I managed to make it work.

```
const TEMP_CATEGORIES = ["major olympian", "twelve titan", "primordial deity"];      
 const _query = {
          '$or': [
            {
              $and: [
                {
                  "name": {
                    "$regex": search,
                    "$options": "i"
                  }
                },
                {
                  category: { $in: TEMP_CATEGORIES }
                }
              ],
            },
            {
              $and: [
                {
                  "category": {
                    "$regex": search,
                    "$options": "i"
                  }
                },
                {
                  category: { $in: TEMP_CATEGORIES }
                }
              ],
            },
          ]
        }; 


 Greek
      .find(_query)
      .sort({ name: 1 })
      .exec((err, greeks) => {
        if (err) {
          console.warn(err);
          reject(err)
        } else {
          resolve(greeks);
        }
      });
  });
```

I don't know if it is the proper way but, it appears to work.(I guess I should unit test it...)